# Why does log by tracing not work when using it in a procedure in TCL/Expect

Tags: linux, automation, tcl, expect

The below code does not output to the sample.log file as intended. Is there a reason why?
Might be related to scope, but cant seem to figure it out.

```
proc log_by_tracing { array element op } {
    uplevel {
        global logfile
        set file $logfile($expect_out(spawn_id))
        puts -nonewline $file $expect_out(buffer)
    }
}

proc start_telnet {} {
 spawn telnet 10.30.16.112
 set logfile($spawn_id) [open sample.log w]
 trace variable expect_out(buffer) w log_by_tracing
 expect  "login"
 send "anonymous\r"


}

start_telnet
```

Help

Answer (score 2):

Probably that uplevel block is failing to substitute what you think. Its really awkward code too. You can pass a variable into the trace function you know and avoid the global and the uplevel.

```
proc log {chan varname elt op} {
    upvar #0 $varname v
    puts -nonewline $chan "< $v(buffer)"
}
proc start_telnet {} {
    set log [open sample.log w]
    trace variable expect_out(buffer) w [list log $log]
    ...
}
```

Comment: That seems fine, but lets say I am interacting with multiple processes, and I want to log all thier output simultaneously! Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `upvar 1 expect_out expect_out` might help; the parent scope of `log` will be the one where it has been set.